# Message when running apt upgrade "No original module was found for this module on this kernel"

Tags: apt, updates, dkms

When I update ubuntu, apt upgrade, this appears,
rtl8723be.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-63-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.
I'm using
Kernel 4.4.0-66-generic
Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

there is something wrong?

The same goes for:
rtl_pci.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-63-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

rtl_usb.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-63-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

rtlwifi.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-63-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

btcoexist.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-63-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

rtl8188ee.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-63-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

rtl8192c-common.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-63-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

rtl8192ce.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-63-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

rtl8192cu.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-63-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

rtl8192de.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-63-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

rtl8192ee.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-63-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

rtl8192se.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-63-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

rtl8723ae.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-63-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

rtl8821ae.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-63-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall anyMessage when running apt upgrade “No original module was found for this module on this kernel”

**With the new update, does not appear "no original module was found for this module on this kernel".
Current kenel 4.4.0-67-generic
Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
64-bit**